# What does this line do, which way round should I read the ternary operator?

Tags: c#

I have this method:

```
public static int SetFlag(this int i, int flag, bool set = true)
{
     return (set) ? i | flag : ((i & flag) != 0) ? (i-flag) : i;

     if(
}
```

Just wondering how to read it. Is it saying there are 2 ternary condictions? Do I read it from right to left or left to right?

Comment: In your shoes, I'd refactor that code, and not bother trying to understand it as it is. Keep it simple.

Comment: @JasonEvans he shouldn't refactor if there isn't a test case written for it :)

Comment: Buy a Resharper license, and you'll be able to just click "replace with if-statement" on that nasty ?: operator

Comment: Code that mixes bitwise logical with addition and subtraction operators is extremely hard to read and reason about. Code that uses nested conditional operators is extremely hard to read and reason about. Code that has two different operations depending on the value of a Boolean is extremely hard to read and reason about.  Code that uses common words like "set" in two different ways -- here to mean both as a verb, to set the flag, and as a noun, the value to set it to -- is extremely hard to read and reason about. This code is only two lines long and it has four really bad problems. Fix it.

Comment: Hi Eric, how can I figura out what is going on then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That code is equivalent to:

```
if (set)
    return i | flag;
else
    if ((i & flag) != 0)
        return i-flag;
    else
        return i;
```

Comment: I know, but it's good for clarification about the syntax. You can even optimize it even more but it wouldn't be as descriptive as explanation for the ternary syntax in the example.

Comment: I'm interested now - how can you optimise it more? :)

Comment: Hah, I didn't figure that you probably meant both else statements, but that was what I was thinking about. Meaning two if statements and otherwise only return.

Answer (score 3):

Yes there are 2 conditions here.

If i break it up, then it looks like

```
    if(set)
{
  return (i| flag);
}
else if((i& flag) != 0)
{
 return (i-flag);
}
else return i;
```

Please note in the above code that there are many return statements and the same is with ternary operator. Though there is no return statement but for readability sake its complex. So its better you refactor the code.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are two ternary operators there. You read it from inside-out, by the parenthesis first, then the ternary operators.

Answer (score 1):

It is two ternary operators. Read it from left to right.

It is equivalent to

```
if (set)
  return i | flag;
else
  if ((i & flag) != 0)
    return i-flag;
  else
    return i;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if set is true

then return i | flag

else if (i&flag) !=0

then return i-flag

else return i
```

Answer (score 0):

Read it like:

```
if (set) {
  return i | flag;
} else {
   return ((i & flag) != 0) ? (i-flag) : i;
}
```

Comment: There is school of thought that the else you used is useless :-)

Comment: Mmmh... I think I saw it in Resharper, so it would be C#

Answer (score 0):

```
return (set) ? i | flag : ((i & flag) != 0) ? (i-flag) : i;
```

equivalent to

```
return (set) ? 
    i | flag : 
    ((i & flag) != 0) ? 
        (i-flag) : 
        i;
```

Clearer now? And I will say that some brackets are useless.

```
return set ? 
    i | flag : 
    (i & flag) != 0 ? 
        i - flag : 
        i;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int result;

if(set){
    result = i | flag;
} else {
    if((i & flag) != 0) {
        result = i - flag;
    } else {
        result = i;
    }
}

return result;
```

**OR**

```
if(set)
    return i | flag;
else if((i & flag) != 0)
    return i - flag;
else
    return i;
```

**OR**

```
if(set)
    return i | flag;
else if((i & flag) != 0)
    return i - flag;
return i;
```

Answer (score 0):

> (set) ? i | flag : ((i & flag) != 0) ? (i-flag) : i

equals this:

```
if (set){
  i | flag
}else{
  if((i & flag) != 0){
    (i-flag)
  }else{
    i
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(set)
    return i | flag;
else if((i & flag) != 0)
    return i - flag;
return i;
```